# Save image from WebView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

I am currently loading html file into `UIWebView`, It is table or png image sometime,i am able to save image and table but it takes image that is visible in `UIWebView`. checkout my code:-

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theWebView.bounds.size);
   // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theWebView.frame.size);
    [theWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Tried at both way, frame & bounds. Bounds gives me full image but its blur & i need to set content to fit to `UIWebView` so that i can zoom & scroll `UIWebView`.

If i set content of `UIWebView` to Center using following code than i am unable to scroll due to Scale page to fit property.

```
NSString *bodyStyle = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'center';";
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyle];
```

How do i set page to center/appropriate that user can scroll & save whole html page to Image in photo album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[theWebView sizeToFit];
```

Worked with above code & adjusted frame of `UIWebView` again.